# Table in a poster

Tags: posters

I am using overleaf environment to create a A0 size poster. The class used for this purpose is 'baposter'. I am trying to use exact table which I had used for the paper submission. However, it is giving errors in poster environment.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait,showframe]{baposter}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}% for customizing the lists
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,ragged2e}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp} % trademark symbol


\headerbox{Experimental Results}{name=results,span=2,column=1,above=future} {
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Inference on IR images using WaSR}
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\dp\strutbox} % the devious trick!
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{\quad} ccc @{}}
         \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{7mm}{\raggedright Original IR images}} &
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  & 
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \\
        \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{7mm}{\raggedright Direct inference}} &
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{7mm}{\raggedright Retrained with gray scale images}} &
        \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
        \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{7mm}{\raggedright Retrained with IR images}} &
        \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
         \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
          \includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
```

And I am getting these errors -

```
LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@xfloat ... \global \setbox \@currbox
\color@vbox \normalcolor \...
l.159 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again>
\vbox
l.159 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

All the errors belong to the last closing curly brace.

This produces a box with the correct title but my beautiful table containing images is missing. What am I missing?

I had posted this question on latex forum and though folks are sincere in their attempt to provide me a solution, it is at best a work around (https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=34274).
If the table can be supported inside header box, that will be really great.

Note that the layout of this table was suggested by folks from this forum (when I was working on paper) so I am hopeful that we can find a solution to my problem, this time for the poster.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that you're trying to put a float (`table`) inside the argument to `\headerbox` which puts its contents inside a `minipage`.

A frequent point of confusion is to think that a `tabular` environment needs to be inside a `table` environment, but the latter environment is about positioning within the document and otherwise has nothing to do with tables (other than how captions are labeled). **You do not need `table` around your `tabular`.**

The simplest approach for what you want is to just remove the `table` environment entirely and use the `\captionof` command to format the caption.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. However, I have a follow-up question which I will have to ask as a separate question because of attachment.